# Cannot access TYPO3 Backend after config change

Tags: typo3, backend, config

I have the following problem:

After trying to change the entry point to my website in the backend of my TYPO3 system (by using  the site config), I cannot access neither my backend nor my frontend of the website anymore. Whenever I try to access the site it says "Oops, an error occurred! The parsedUri "https://" appears to be malformed".

What I have tried, is accessing the config.yaml on my webserver to change the baseURL inside of the config, but no matter what I change it to, it doesn't seem to work, as I always get the same error message even uploading the changed config file (what I mean by that is, that the text inside the error message doesn't change to reflect the new url but stays "https://").

I hope that someone who is more experienced in TYPO3 can help me solve this issue. I couldn't really find a working solution after extensively searching so far. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After changing the yaml file of the site configuration, you need to clear all caches, either via the install tool (yourdomain.tld/typo3/install.php) or by deleting all files in the directories var/cache/code and var/cache/data.